# Распарсить строку с помощью regex Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

К примеру есть строка "1459,john,25,y". Как из строки получить tuple ('john', 25), где john и 25 - второй и третий элемент.

Сделал вариант ниже, но получаю на выходе list, вместо tuple

```
result = re.findall(r"(?<=\,)\w+(?<!\,)\w+", "1459,john,25,y")

["john", "25"]
```

Comment: Например "1459,john,25,y".split(',')[1:-1]

Comment: Прежде чем решать такую задачу, нужно знать, почему нужно получить именно ('john', 25)? Это второй и третий элементы? Это имя и число после него? Это предпоследний и предпредпоследний элементы? Какая-то иная логика? Что нужно получить из похожей строки "34,234,mark,124"? А из "john,mark,1827,25"?

Comment: Верно, john и 25 второй и третий элементы. Первый всегда число, а четвертый только одна буква.

Comment: ну тогда элементарно сплитить по запятой и взять второй и третий элементы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: это да, но мне было не понятно можно ли это регуляркой сделать

Comment: Если сплитом получилось, то регуляркой и подавно :)

Answer (score 1):

Ну если уж нужен кортеж, а не список, то список элементарно конвертируется в кортеж:

```
result = tuple(re.findall(r"(?<=\,)\w+(?<!\,)\w+", "1459,john,25,y"))
```